# cin 'stalling' c++ program

Tags: c++, cin

I'm new to c++ and trying to learn via sample programs. 
When running this program it gets stuck on cin >> n;
It allows me to type information, but then after pressing 'enter' nothing happens.
The program continues to run indefinitely doing nothing and I have to shut it off in task manager. Thanks :)
Edit: The problem only happens when running from sublime text 3. The compiled program runs fine in the command prompt.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;

    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    cin >> n;

    if ( n % 2 == 0)
        cout << n << " is even.";
    else
        cout << n << " is odd.";

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Here is the results of running the program from sublime text. 
'Enter an integer: 10'
Nothing else happens.

Comment: What are you entering for input?

Comment: Can you show exactly how you are invoking the program, showing it's output and the input you entered on the command line? Also showing how the program was compiled might help. Also, Ctrl-C should kill the program without using Task Manager.

Comment: When the `cin >> n` can't read an integer, it fails.  You should test the operation and handle the error case.

Comment: AndyG - Happens when I enter an integer or anything else.

Comment: @pcarter - I'm not sure how you'd like me to show the output. Can I send a screen shot? I'm compiling in Sublime Text 3 with MinGW.

Comment: There is a question on this page about why a certain program goes into an infinite loop when someone enters an invalid input character.  It has an example on how to properly check for a failed cin state. https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#stream-input-failure

Comment: No, don't do a screen shot. Compile and run your program in a command window. Then copy and paste the text from the window into your question. When I compile your code and run it, it works fine. So you must be doing something wrong in the compile and run steps.

Comment: @pcarter It seems the problem is with running in sublime text 3. The compiled file runs fine in the command prompt. The output from sublime is as follows. 'Enter an integer: 10' after pressing ENTER there is no further output. just the blinking cursor.

Comment: I don't use Sublime, but a quick google found this page that seems describe the same problem: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/build-broken-python-3-input/44988 The simplest solution would be run from the command line.

Comment: Yeah, That's probably what I will end up doing. Or perhaps download a better IDE. Thanks for the input.